# Using JSON to store data in a text file

Tags: c#, .net, json

I need to store some data relative to a library in some text files, customers and books.
I've been searching about how to save data with JSON to a text file but I couldn't understand the codes or which namespaces I should call.

I was searching for the typical JSON structure something like:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "address": "Street of whatever",
  "ID": 123456789,
  "telephone": 123443221,
  "gender": "M",
  "prefgenres": {
    "adventure": true,
    "romance": false,
    "police": true,
    "scifi": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you serialize the model holding the JSON structure in the server end and save that to a xml file?

Comment: It's required to use text files.

Comment: If you "couldn't understand the codes" please explain what exact help you are looking from SO with this question. Clearly someone will provide you with code, but explaining what you have trouble with may help you better.

Comment: What do you mean text files? XML files can be opened with notepad and saved with .txt extension if required.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov couldn't understand how the info was serialized.

Comment: @SILENT ah! I thought you were speaking about a .xml file... Yeah I see what you meant now. Can you help me with that? It sounds a very nice idea too.

Comment: @DiogoMartinho What makes JSON more "texty" than XML? Both formats are computer-parsable text, both have strict requirements about character encoding, and both are well supported by many languages.

Comment: Nothing but, I've already worked with JSON on the web and I like it :) just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), it is really simple to use.

To simplify your research, if you just want to serialize a simple object you can do this:

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace test
{
    public void writeObject( object myObj){ 
        using (StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter(myPath))
        { 
            newFile.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));
        }   
    }
}
```

To deserialize your data you can use this:

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace test
{
    public MyObject readObject(){
        var result;  
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(myPath))
        { 
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(file.ReadToEnd());
            file.Close();
        }   
        return result;
    }
} //Notice that "MyObject" could be even a collection of your objects, like List<Customer> and you can deserialize all in once.
```

Comment: Note that your post does not answer actual question - " couldn't understand how the info was serialized"

Comment: I really dont see that question. Where is it?

Comment: In comment by OP on what help is actually needed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572764/using-json-to-store-data-in-a-text-file/29572843?noredirect=1#comment47294879_29572764

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry, I wasn't reading the comments.

Comment: This is working for the writting, thank you! I will check out tomorrow how do I read from file and save it to my array of customers.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a way to deserialize. You should read the Json.Net documents anyway. Hope it works for you! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your model

```
[Serializable]
class Contact
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public Contact()
    {

    }
}
```

Saving Method

```
    internal static class Source
    {
        internal static bool Save<T>(T data, string saveFilePath)
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                using (var usw = new Utf8StringWriter())
                {
                    ser.Serialize(usw, data);
                    sw.Write(usw.ToString());
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Calling Saving Method

```
Source.Save(contactmodel, "contact.txt");
```

Comment: This looks interesting, might give it a try, but I was hopping to use JSON now. Anyway, thanks for your help!